# laravel : sanitize request data before validation

Tags: validation, laravel, request, rules

there is a `UpdateUserRequest` form request that verify fields value against its rules defined in `rules` mathod .it has rules() and authorize() methods by default. i want prevent verifying and updating empty fields (such as password) .

using `sometimes` in rules is not useful as html inputs will be present in POST request even if they are empty.

```
array:6 [▼
 "_method" => "PATCH"
 "_token" => "Cz79rRez2f6MG0tTU17nVwXD0X1lNGH1hA7OORjm"
 "name" => "john"
 "email" => "mymail@gmail.com"
 "password" => ""
 "password_confirmation" => ""

]
```

so i should remove empty keys of POST request before using `sometimes` in rules.
the question is : Where is the best place to purge Request array?
is there any laravel build in method to manage such situations?

**P.S** :Solution:
@Bogdon solution is still valid and works, but there is another simple ,nice ,neat solution adopted from [here](http://larabrain.com/tips/sanitizing-form-data-before-validating-in-a-laravel-5-form-request):
*just override `all()` method inside form request*

```
 class RegistrationRequest extends Request
  {

...

public function all()
{
    $attributes = parent::all();

    if(isset($attributes['password']) && empty($attributes['password'])) 
        {
            unset($attributes['password']);
        }
    $this->replace($attributes);

    return parent::all();

}

...

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make this work you'll need to modify the contents of the `App\Http\Requests\Request` class to allow a way to sanitize the input (class code taken from [this Laracasts post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-modify-input-before-validation/replies/34366)):

```php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

abstract class Request extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Validate the input.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Factory  $factory
     * @return \Illuminate\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validator($factory)
    {
        return $factory->make(
            $this->sanitizeInput(), $this->container->call([$this, 'rules']), $this->messages()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize the input.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function sanitizeInput()
    {
        if (method_exists($this, 'sanitize'))
        {
            return $this->container->call([$this, 'sanitize']);
        }

        return $this->all();
    }
}
```

After that you just need to write add `sanitize` method in the `UpdateUserRequest` class that removes the `password` field from the input when it's empty:

```php
public function sanitize()
{
    if (empty($this->get('password'))) {
        // Get all input
        $input = $this->all();
        // Remove the password field
        unset($input['password']);
        // Replace the input with the modified one
        $this->replace($input);
    }

    return $this->all();
}
```

Now using the `sometimes` rule for the password field will work:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // Other rules go here
        'password' => 'sometimes|required|confirmed'
    ];
}
```

Comment: thanks.but what if the user is intended to change his password?password should be intact when its field is empty, and should be updated when password field is filled.by the way i have two request forms , one for create new user and one for update user. also i think there is no need to add `password_confirmation` in rules, just add `confirmed` to `password` .

Comment: My bad, you're right, I was trying to make a point about password confirmation and I added the `confirmed` rule incorrectly :). Aside from that, if the user intends to update the password just don't include the `update` field (or if it's included make sure the value is not `1`). In short: **if the request data contains an `update=1` field then the password is optional, otherwise it's required**.

Comment: you've focused on rules,while im looking for a place(method) to purge request date before verifying against rules and before passing that data to update method in controller. in fact im thinking about something like `register` and `boot` methods in service provider that `register ` has priority to `boot` .

Comment: Oh sorry, I got stuck with my own idea, I understand now. I've updated my answer updated with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the best way to purge the fields, but this is how I currently handle user updates on my system.

I find the user based on the `$id` passed through and then update the appropriate records. I assume that `name` and `email` will never be empty, it is only the password that can be empty - and so we can just set the `name` and `email` fields to the values passed in and then use an `if` statement to check if the `password` field is empty or not and update accordingly.

Something along the lines of this is what I use:

```
public function update($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);

        $user->name   = Input::get('name');
        $user->email      = Input::get('email');
        if (Input::get('password') != "")
        {
        $user->password   = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
        }

        $user->save();
    }
```